# Can we define Session State Mode (inproc, custom, etc) per controller in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Can we define Session State Mode on controller wise in asp.net MVC 3?
We know, Session State Behavior such as Default, Required, etc can be defined.

```
 [SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.Default)]
 public class HomeController : Controller
 {
 }
```

But not sure we can define Session State Mode like below

```
 [SessionState(SessionStateMode.InProc)]
 public class HomeController : Controller
 {
 }
```

Comment: Not as far as I know. Why would you want to do that anyway?

Comment: Currently I am using Custom Mode across application. I have specific controller where performance is very slow due to that. So I am trying use Inproc mode for that particular controller.

Comment: Here's what I don't understand though, you obviously selected Custom because it solved a problem that neither SQLServer nor StateServer addressed. I would think that problem could potentially exist across your site, thus requiring that all controllers use the same session state store. Also, that one controller wouldn't be able to access the state that any of the other controllers set (and vice versa). It's almost sounding this maybe that one controller actually represents a separate site.